# How to write integrals symbolically in Sagemath similar to Mathematica

Tags: mathematica, sagemath

In Mathematica you can input an integral symbolically by entering `esc` int `esc`. See the reference under the `Details and Options` section: [∫ can be entered as `esc` int `esc`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html). Does Sagemath have this functionality?

Comment: I don't know for certain that this can't be done, which is why I'm leaving a comment instead of an answer, but I think the answer is "no". I'm not aware of any way to symbolically write an integral in the input to a sagecell (let's say in a Jupyter notebook). That said, there are other latex symbols that you can use (as variables, etc.) by entering the latex command and hitting tab. See [here](https://github.com/ellisonbg/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/latex_symbols.py) for (what I believe to be) a complete list

Comment: You could post at ask.sagemath.org to get a more focused audience for the question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've done so: https://ask.sagemath.org/question/64013/how-to-write-integrals-symbolically-in-sagemath-similar-to-mathematica/